# System running in low-graphics mode

Tags: lenovo

Last day I saw this error:

```
 “The system is running in low-graphics mode”
```

I tired some methods to fix but didn't worked for me so I re-installed ubuntu.

I just installed few apps today and everything was working fine... but now I see again this error message.

I have tried some methods from askubuntu and ubuntuforums but none of theme was not working for me.

Here you can see my Graphic details:

[image]

### [image]

I dont have nvidia graphics! https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr5UQ.jpg

What should i do?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show what your graphics adapter is.  Just various parts of your other hardware.  Try `lspci | grep VGA` or `lspci | grep vga` - whichever lists your card.

Comment: `lspci | grep -i vga` searches case-insensitively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: Here you can see my graphics adapter details: https://i.imgur.com/VZOKqP2.jpg

Comment: Please use `lspci -nn | grep "\[03"` instead.

Comment: Here is what P.-H. Lin wanted to see: https://i.imgur.com/gDRX2Oh.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can try and turn off the switchable graphics in the BIOS:

Reboot your computer, enter the BIOS settings  and change them from:

- switchable graphics
- Hybrid graphics
- ...

to:

- UMA graphics
- On-board graphics
- Intel Graphics
- ...

  after that, it will be possible to use the Intel video card only with proper drivers on Ubuntu.

<sub>[Here is the source of my material](http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/07/ubuntu-1404-lenovo-g510.html)</sub>

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: @Fabby I did just that

Comment: It still needed editing.  **:P**  Please look at my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/701300/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby thank you for editing my post, you just had too didnt you :p

Comment: And upvoted!  :P

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in the past with my NVidia graphics card.  I don't know if there is something similar for your Lenovo system.  For what it's worth, since there may be others with NVida problems, here is what I do/did:

1. Log out of X:
   sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop
   Screen will go black with the last white messages from bootup.
2. will give you a login prompt.  Log in to get a command line prompt.
3. sudo su, cd to /root, then execute:
   ./NVIDIA-Linux_x86_169.12-pkg1.run
   (Tab key will allow auto completion -- the version numbers may have changed.)  This will give a screen-app with prompts for you to follow:

   Accept license (need to make it white highlighted)

   Allow removal of previous 169.12

   Allow it to go to web for a new version of something.

   Allow it to rebuilt the X configuration file.

   Accept the "OK" when it says it is done.

This will return you to the command line prompt.

4. (Still as root from above su): 'reboot'